# Create a ruby function that takes a string input and applies the string as a method?

Tags: ruby

Suppose we want `social_link(user, social)` to return the user's social media link, how can we define that function so that the 'social' argument is used as a method on the `user` argument?

i.e.

if `social_link(user, "facebook")`, then it would run

```rb
user.facebook
```

or if `social_link(user, "twitch")`, then:

```rb
user.twitch
```

and so on, with the key idea being that the function should take the string argument and call that string as a method on another object.

i.e something like

```rb
def social_link(user, social) 
  user.<social>
end
```

What is the syntax required to make this kind of function work?

Comment: `user.public_send(social)` is the syntax you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
As @stefan has pointed out the syntax you're probably looking for is:

```rb
user.public_send(social)
```

I think I saw the word "define" and jumped to this response below. The original response shouldn't be used carelessly.

Original:

Yes, ruby has the syntax you're looking for with `define_method` and `method_missing`:

```rb
class User
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    self.class.send(:define_method, m) do |args|
      puts args
    end
    send(m, args)
  end

  def facebook(args)
    puts args
    puts "do the fb thing"
  end
end

u = User.new
u.instagram("does the instagram thing")
u.twitch("does the twitch thing")
```

In ruby "everything is an object." So when we use the `instance.method` syntax, what's really going on is we're sending `instance` the "message" `method` where the `.` (dot operator) is essentially the "send" operator.

`method_missing` is the method/function that receives "unknown messages." Here, we're intercepting the "message," in this case "instagram," defining it on the fly then sending the `*args` to that method `m`.

Comment: Just googling those terms. Look forward to the example. Upvoted

Comment: some other keywords that you might find helpful in the process are `responds_to?`, `alias`, and `instance_variable_set`, there are others but these will lead you to those ha

Comment: The question is about _calling_ existing methods dynamically, not about creating new ones.